# Programmatically select SOME text in a textarea or input

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for a way to programmatically select specific text inside of an input or textarea.

E.g.

`$('#my-input').val(); // "This is some text"`

I'm aware that `.select()` will select all contents in the input field.

Any way to programmatically select just the word "text" with no user interaction?

Comment: how do we know to look for 'text'? Is it that specific string or something else?

Comment: You'll need to be more specific about how, and what, you want to select. Are you looking for a specific word, set of words, etc?

Comment: First find where it is (`strpos`) then set `area = document.getElementById('my-input'); area.selectionStart = ___; area.selectionEnd = ___;`

Comment: impossible if no limitation/specification. but you can get such as the last word, last N letters, or one specific word of a selected list of words....

Comment: Awesome. Wasn't even aware of setSelectionRange - thanks @trincot.

Comment: "text" could be anything, but is just a specific substring that we're looking for.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol @trincot both are great approaches. Just need to use `indexOf` to get the string position first and then set the selection. Thanks!

Comment: If you know the word, do you really need to select it? Or is knowing the word is present in the field good enough?